# reverting from emacs keybindings in chrome

Tags: chromium, gconf, emacs

I enabled emacs keybindings as an experiment using gconftool-2 and setting /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme to Emacs.  I wasn't happy with it and set it back to Default.

```
jeff@london:~ $ gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme
Default
jeff@london:~ $
```

But chrome continues to interpret keybindings as emacs.  C-a goes to beginning of line rather than selecting all, C-k kills current line rather than beginning a web search, etc.

I find plenty of references online on how to set emacs bindings, but removing them again is proving harder.  Any suggestions on what to look for?  (It is possible, of course, that I did something or that something happened beyond the gconftool-2 setting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've documented this in [bug 985834](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/985834).

The heart of the resolution is this:

> This was not, in the end, a chromium-browser problem but a gnome problem. Oddly, gconftool showed the problem fixed when it wasn't. But gnome-tweak-tool showed the key bindings still to be emacs, and changing that back to Default fixed the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried using [`gconf-editor`](http://www.fettesps.com/ubuntu-emacs-keybindings/)?

Comment: And btw, can you share how you changed the setting to use emacs keybind? I've been looking for the way to enable emacs key on my `Chrome` on `Oneiric` but not successful.

Comment: I opened it up as a new question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124815/enabling-emacs-keybind-on-google-chrome

Comment: I think you've answered your own question in 124815.  gconftool and gconf-editor are two ways to access the same information (commandline and gui).  To get emacs bindings, set the value for key /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme to Emacs.