# Kubuntu 13.10 Emacs Binding in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gtk

I like to use Emacs keybinding such as CTRL-A beginning of line in all my browsers. I have it working fine in Firefox, but not in Google Chrome.

I followed the instructions in 
[How do I enable Emacs keybindings in apps, such as Google Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124815/how-do-i-enable-emacs-keybindings-in-google-chrome)

as well as having  ~/.gtkrc-2.0 include the line

```
gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"
```

None of these seem to affect Chrome.

Comment: And magically it started working. Not sure if it's something I did or just routine apt-get update.