# Emacs Keybinding customization

Tags: emacs, text-editor, gnome-tweak-tool

I have just discovered that using gnome-tweak-tool it is possible to use emacs keybindings inside every input field and I think this is an amazing feature. Anyway I would like to customize this feature to match my particular emacs keybinding, e.g. delete a whole word with Ctrl-h instead of Ctrl-w. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please link to where you learned that it's possible with `gnome-tweak-tool`? I currently only have Emacs keybindings in Emacs (obviously) and in FF via [Firemacs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemacs/).

Comment: Just check in gnome-tweak-tool anyway [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124815/how-do-i-enable-emacs-keybindings-in-apps-such-as-google-chrome) is a reference.