# Xubuntu 12.04: How to get Emacs keybindings?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, xfce, emacs

I work with Xubuntu 12.04 on a MacBook Air. There are various posts about how to use Emacs' keybindings under gnome (see, for example, [How do I enable Emacs keybindings in apps, such as Google Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124815/enabling-emacs-keybind-on-google-chrome), [reverting from emacs keybindings in chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123073/reverting-from-emacs-keybindings-in-chrome), or http://www.fettesps.com/ubuntu-emacs-keybindings/).

I installed gconf-editor and replaced "Greybird" by "Emacs" in desktop -> gnome -> interface -> gtk_theme. This change did not seem to have an effect, though.

How can I get Emacs keybindings under Xubuntu? [C-s for "search" and C-y for "paste" in google chrome, for example]

Answer (score 3):

Found here: http://iomem.com/archives/22-Emacs-keybindings-with-XFCE.html

xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/KeyThemeName -s Emacs

Comment: In principle, this seems okay (C-a, C-e works), but C-y for example does not work...